# Why is it hard to give a lattice definition of string theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, discrete, lattice-model

In Polyakov's book, he explains that one possible way to compute the propagator for a point particle is to compute the lattice sum $\sum_{P_{x,x'}}\exp(-m_0L[P_{x,x'}])$, where the sum goes over all paths between $x$ and $x'$. One then needs to compute this sum and choose the bare mass so that there's a good continuum limit.

Polyakov then goes on to say that this doesn't work for string theory. I skimmed the literature and couldn't find any explanation of this fact. Naively I would think that in order to find the propagator, you could just compute the sum $\sum_{W_{C,C'}}\exp(-T_0 A[W_{C,C'}])$, where the sum is over worldsheets that end on the curves $C$ and $C'$. What goes wrong? Is this just a hard sum to do?

Answer (score -5):

M theory and string theory both have propogators and Feynman diagrams.

The concrete form of the propagators can be easily
obtained, since the problem can be mapped onto the problem of finding the
propagators for the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator.

See:Becker and Matrix theory as wells as string field theory

Also the SO32 closed string is an E8xE8 even lattice.

Comment: That's not true. M-theory does not have any precise formulation in terms of a perturbative expansion. Also I don't understand in what sense saying that some theory has a good perturbative expansion shows the difficulties in trying to put it on a lattice.

Comment: Can I ask, How do M branes evolve if not a path integral.A propogator is a time evolution operator,not a pertubative method. What we change essentially in M theory is the branes and the integral, making it a volume integral

Comment: On what parameter could you possibly define $M$-theory as a perturbative expansion using the path integral ? $M$-theory free of parameters.

Comment: Perubative expansion does not mean propogator. For instance S duality allows for compactification proportinal to -1/t. Thus ads/cft but in general compactification is a an evolution of the metric.You define the M brane connected by a flux.

Path integrals are not equal to pertubative expansions. Are you thinking about the Riemann integral as the limit to an infinite sum?

Comment: Everything you have written is complete nonsense. Just a bunch of words without any real meaning.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear,srry. Open Becker and Swartz to page M theory. M theory is so32 are linked by a duality. A T duality, it low energy LIMIT is a 11 dimensional supergravity. A path integral is a time evolution method,an S matrix or if you want Green function.

A Rimenean sum Is a whoe different thing. 

S Duality means that our action is invariant to changes such as 2pir=-1/t
I ask again, how do you think we change the metric in ads/cft.

Comment: You're not answering the question. Why is hard to give a lattice definition of string theory? Saying that a given theory has a good perturbative expansion does not answer, why is difficult to give a lattice definition of it. You're just pretending to know, but you don't.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low-quality and voted for deletion.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't help I was only discussing,next time I'll leave at as comment.

Comment: The question is about obtaining a theory (in this case, string theory) by working on discretized space-time then taking continuum limit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_field_theory